# Back Button duplicates, appearing without configuration Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-2010, mobile, flutter-layout, back

I am developing an app in Flutter, and I added a back button to a certain page, now this button shows everywhere in the code. How do I make sure that this button is only displayed in the pages I want? Not in whole code after pressing the back button? I am posting down the main and the page where I created the back button, this is the only class where I added the back button.

The Code

```
import 'package:MECTS_Mobile_Application/Home/routes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget{
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _Home();
}

class _Home extends State<Home> {
 var services = [
'Track Routes',
'View Vehicles',
'View Reports',
 ];

 var images = [
'imageapp/cardone.png',
'imageapp/cardtwo.png',
'imageapp/cardthree.png',
];

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 void move(){
   Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(Routes.routeName);
 }

return GridView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:80.0),
  itemCount: 3,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 1,
    childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/6),
  ),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
    return Card(
      child: Column(children: <Widget> [
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
          width: 20,
        ),
          Image.asset(images[index],height:65,width: 750,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: move,
            child: Text(services[index], 
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), 
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            )
            )
            ),
          ],
         ),
        );
      },
   );
 }
}
```

The Main Page:

```
      import 'package:MECTS_Mobile_Application/Authentication/login_page.dart';
      import 'package:MECTS_Mobile_Application/Authentication/register_page.dart';
      import 'package:MECTS_Mobile_Application/Home/reports.dart';
      import 'package:MECTS_Mobile_Application/Home/splashscreen.dart';
      import 'package:MECTS_Mobile_Application/Home/vehicles.dart';
      import 'Home/routes.dart';
      import 'root.dart';
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


       void main() {
     runApp(new MyApp());
     }

     class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'MECTS',
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.cyan),
      home: new SplashMECTSScreen(),
      routes: {
    LoginPage.routeName: (ctx) => LoginPage(),
    RegisterPage.routeName: (ctx) => RegisterPage(),
    Routes.routeName: (ctx) => Routes(),
    Reports.routeName: (ctx) => Reports(),
    Vehicles.routeName: (ctx) => Vehicles(),
    RootPage.routeName: (ctx) => RootPage(),
    },
   );
  }
 }
```

The screens
[image: This is the screen before any action]

[image: This is after clicking in one of the options]

[image: After trying to return to the main page, the button doesn't disapear]

Comment: Can you add the code for the button

Comment: My guess is that you use `Navigator.push()` to go back from the track routes page to the home page instead of `Navigator.pop()`. `Navigator.push()` automatically creates a back button for you which directs to the previous page. What happens when you click the back button?

Comment: Thank you, Navigator.push() did the trick

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem was using:

```
Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(RootPage.routeName);
```